# About iOS development. The launch screen didn't show when I run my project on my iPhone6,however,its's show when run on simulator iPhone6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I don't know why, and this is the first time i came accross this issue.
**NOTE:I had set the launch screen**

Comment: I suggest you clean and rerun.I met and it's a bug of Xcode,I think.

Comment: Try to delete that app from simulate also.

Comment: Oh，it is a bug，I think so

Comment: I had try as you say ，but it is no use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What iOS is your device on?

In xCode 6/iOS8 you use a Xib as your launch screen, older versions use just an image set in assets. (look at your project 'General' settings under 'App Icons and Launch Images' and check to see what is set.

[image]

This article explains a bit more:

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-a-launch-screen-storyboard/

Comment: I solved this problem with your way perfectly,and the link you gave is very useful.Thank you for your answer sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

You can add LaunchImage in Image Assets ad use LaunchImage in Image Assets as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate LaunchImage as follow..[image]